# Is stream.end() synchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, fs

I have a class that has a maintains an instance variable called `write_stream`. This `write_stream` variable gets updated with new write streams and currently I do something like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

class Test {

   constructor() {
      this.write_stream = null;
   }

   ...

   set_write_stream(new_file_path) {
      if (this.write_stream != null) {
         this.write_stream.end();
      }
      this.write_stream = fs.createWriteStream(new_file_path);
   }
}
```

Is this an acceptable way to do this? Is there a better way to do it? Is `stream.end()` synchronous, or do I need to wait for some sort of promise before continuing onto `fs.createWriteStream()`?

Comment: Why do you care if `end()` is async ? Calling it means that you can't write to that stream any longer (*that* effect is immediate), and eventually the buffer will drain and the stream will emit "finish". Your class has no responsibility to wait until then, does it ? Maybe you want to make sure all the files have been written before exiting the app ?

Comment: @Touffy you're right, for some reason I felt like changing the variable would affect the outcome of the `.end()` call, but it won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback) say that `writable.end()` takes a callback

You can also promisify and await the callback like so:

```js
const p = new Promise(res => this.write_stream.end(res))
await p;
```

Although, I don't think you should to wait for the first stream to finish before replacing it on the object. That might lead to a race condition where something tries to write to the already ended but not totally finished stream.

In other words, if something tries to .write() the stream after you call .end() it will error, so you must replace the stream right after you call .end() in order for it to be seamless.

Comment: I just tested this code in node v13.12.0 because i wasn't sure myself, but it seemed to work fine. The callback is needed even without additional data because it may take time to flush the data in the stream buffer already.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I think this would be the correct answer.

Comment: So just to clarify, the above code is how one would return a promise with `stream.end()`, but you recommend that I don't due to a possible race condition? So in the current state of my code there is no race condition, and therefore it must be the case that `stream.end()` is synchronous?

Comment: stream.end() is not synchronous. what that practically means is that you need to keep listening for "error" events until the callback is called or until the "finish" event is emitted. Your current code avoids a possible race condition, I'll try to update my answer to be more clear.